# ggplot2 map admin borders over lower-admin fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a shapefile of India that I turned into an sf object, and I'm mapping district-level values using `ggplot2` using code like the following:

```
ggplot(data = distVDS) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = dstexp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#238b45", "#66c2a4","#b2e2e2","#FFFFFF", "#fdcc8a", "#fc8d59", "#d7301f"), 
                    name="category", 
                    labels = c("lab1","lab2","lab3","lab4","lab5","lab6","lab7"))
```

While the polygons that I'm filling represent India's districts, I have 2 shapefile fields that provide state codes and state names. States in India are larger than / contain districts, like US states are larger than / contain counties.

How can I draw a light gray or thicker black border around the states, a border that goes on top of the existing district borders? My state fields are `distVDS$STCODE` (integer class) and `distVDS$STNAME` (character class), and they are never missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how your question is worded, I'm assuming the only polygon data you have are the districts themselves. Even though they have identifier fields for the name and corresponding code of the larger state they fall within, if there's no associated polygon data for the *states*, then you'll need to obtain a separate shapefile of Indian states. Once you have that, though, you can just add another call  to `geom_sf` to your existing code, change the line-width and color to achieve a thicker black/grey border, set `fill=NA` outside of a call to `aes()`, and then set any other stylings to your map that you'd like to achieve your desired result.

I've put together a quick sample dataset using median household income by county in 3 US states to demonstrate this:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ark_la_tx <- tigris::states() |>
  dplyr::filter(STATEFP=="48" | STATEFP=="22" | STATEFP=="40")

ark_la_tx_counties <- tidycensus::get_acs(
  geography = "county",
  variables = "B19013_001", # Median household income by county
  output = "wide",
  state = c("TX", "LA", "OK"),
  geometry = TRUE
)
    
ggplot() +
  # Smaller administrative level goes first
  geom_sf(
    data = ark_la_tx_counties,
    aes(fill = B19013_001E) 
  ) +
  # Larger administrative level goes after with no fill
  geom_sf(
    data = ark_la_tx,
    lwd = 1,
    color = "#000000",
    fill = NA
  ) +
  theme_void()
```

And the final result:
[image: Choropleth map of Arkansas, Louisiana & Texas showing median household income by county with state borders drawn on top of county lines.]

Edit: Since you don't already have the states shapefile, you can create one by dissolving districts together based on `distVDS$STNAME`. In my example, this would be `STATE_NAME`. Both

```
ark_la_tx_dissolved <- ark_la_tx_counties |>
  dplyr::group_by(STATE_NAME) |>
  dplyr::summarise()
```

Calling just `summarise()` by itself by default will assume you want to use the `st_union()` function. Then you can just replace the `data` argument of the second instance of `geom_sf()` above with the new `ark_la_tx_dissolved` object and it'll show the same result as above.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. But indeed, I do NOT have a state shapefile, and in fact it doens't exist as far as I know, because these are 1966 districts and 1966 states. So I don't think there's a shapefile for 1966 states out there. Can you perhaps tell me how I would dissolve the borders of the district-level shapefile to CREATE the state-level shapefile? Using the state-level fields I named above? I'm actually trying to do this right now (with gUnaryUnion) but it's not working. I'm not even sure if this dissolve is best done before I turn my shapefile into an sf object or after.

Comment: The only method I know of is `st_union` from the `sf` package. So for instance, if I wanted to create Louisiana's state shape by combining all of its component counties, I would use `louisiana <- st_union(dplyr::filter(ark_la_tx_counties, STATE_NAME=="Louisiana"))`. I could then check my work using a quick call to `ggplot() + geom_sf(data = louisiana) + theme_void()`.

Comment: But there is no way to dissolve the counties within EACH state, but maintaining ALL states? I don't really want to have to add 15 states 1 by 1 to each map. I want a single file that provides all state borders. The sp package did have this capability, I know I've used it before, though I can't find the code. It would be surprising to me if sf truly couldn't do this.

Comment: I've edited my original answer thanks to wisdom in this other SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625471/create-new-geometry-on-grouped-column-in-r-sf

Comment: Awesome! This code for making the larger admin area is super short and works perfectly, thank you so much.